# How to sync mysql local db with AWS cloud database

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

I’m working on my project: cloud tool for cancer data prediction. But I don’t know how to sync MySQL local DB with AWS cloud DB.
I developed a website with MAMP stack on my Mac system, This website is a patient management system which can be used to insert, query, update or delete patient data. I also setup ann AWS EC2 instance which has LAMP stack. The requirement is: any changes in the local database (including insert, query, update or deletion) need to sync with cloud database which means any change can trigger a corresponding change in AWS MySQL database. Could anyone please help with this? What’s the best solution about it? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options, since you're hosting on EC2 I would look at these options. This changes somewhat if you're hosted on AWS RDS or something instead of your own on EC2.

1. Set up MySQL replication between the servers. Your internal server can act as the Master, and the web host server as the slave. Any updates performed on the Master will be replicated to the slave immediately (assuming a working connection). This will most likely be the easiest and most effective option to choose. To use replication, your internal database would need to be accessible over the network from the web host.

You can read more about replication [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html).

2. Each day, you can perform a mysqldump on the internal server, upload the dump file to the web host, and import the data. Since this is a full dump, if you have a very large database, this might not be feasible. If you like, this procedure could potentially be scripted to avoid having to do it manually.
3. You can set up [binary logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html) on the internal server. You can then ship the binary logs to the web host and apply them to the database, effectively playing all transactions that occurred that day to the web server. In effect, this is what happens with replication anyway, so you would nearly always go with the replication set up instead of this option.

If there is no connection between the two databases, taking mysqldumps each day will be the easiest path to take.

Comment: Thanks, @Benloper I try to make it via method 1. But I found I have no public IP for my local server. Thus, perhaps I have to set up another cloud server with public IP.

Comment: Yes, you can set up a public mysql RDS database and then proxy into it. You might want to sync something like MySQLWorkbench to it so you can move around a little bit easier.